# How to use sml to write a function to turn a list of 2-tuples to a flattened list?

Tags: list, function, sml

I got a problem that needs to turn a list of tuples into a flattened list for example:

[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)] can be turned into [1,2,3,4,5,6]

I have tried to write a function like this:

```
fun helper2(nil,b) = []
|   helper2(a,nil) = []
|   helper2(a::l1,b::l2) =l1::l2

fun flatten2 [] = []
|   flatten2 ((a,b)::tl) = helper2(a,b)
```

It shows:

```
val flatten2 = fn : ('a list * 'a list list) list -> 'a list list
```

And when I tried to run it using command `flatten2[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)];`
It will give me the following error message:

```
stdIn:1.2-1.29 Error: operator and operand do not agree [overload conflict]
  operator domain: ('Z list * 'Z list list) list
  operand:         ([int ty] * [int ty]) list
  in expression:
    flatten2 ((1,2) :: (3,4) :: (<exp>,<exp>) :: nil)
```

My questions are:

1. Why SML see the a and b values as lists, not just simply a and b
2. How can I revise my code so SML can see a and b as 'a and 'b not lists
3. How to make this code work the way it should be?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why SML see the a and b values as lists, not just simply a and b

Chris already answered this in-depth.

You're passing `a` as the first argument to `helper2`, which expects a list as its first argument. And you're passing `b` as the second argument to `helper2`, which uses its second argument, `b::l2`, also a list, as the tail of a list where `a` is the head. So `b` must be a list of those lists.

This doesn't make any sense, and is most likely a consequence of confusing syntax: You are passing in what you think of single elements `a` and `b` in `flatten2`, but when you deal with them in `helper2` they're now *lists* where the heads are called `a` and `b`. Those are not the same `a` and `b`.

> How can I revise my code so SML can see a and b as 'a and 'b not lists

You could ditch the helper function to begin with:

```
fun flatten2 []             = []
  | flatten2 ((a,b)::pairs) = a :: b :: flatten2 pairs
```

The purpose of having a helper function is so that it can accumulate the result during recursion, because this version of `flatten2` uses a lot of stack space. It can do this with an extra argument so that `flatten2` doesn't need to mention it:

This is the version Chris made.

> How to make this code work the way it should be?

You can make this code in a lot of ways. Two ways using explicit recursion were mentioned.

Here are some alternatives using higher-order functions:

```
(* Equivalent to my first version *)
fun flatten2 pairs =
  foldr (fn ((a,b), acc) => a :: b :: acc) [] pairs

(* Equivalent to Chris'es version *)
fun flatten2 pairs =
  rev (foldl (fn ((a,b), acc) => b :: a :: acc) [] pairs)

(* Yet another alternative *)
fun concatMap f xs =
  List.concat (List.map f xs)

fun flatten2 pairs =
  concatMap (fn (a,b) => [a,b]) pairs
```

Answer (score 4):

First question: As to why the type comes out as `('a list * 'a list list)` it's because type inference is looking at this part of the code:

```
|   helper2(a::l1,b::l2) =l1::l2
                            ^^
                           here
```

Keep in mind that the type of the "cons" (`::`) operator is `'a -> 'a list -> 'a list`, it is gluing a *single element* onto a list of that same type of element. So SML has concluded that whatever `l1` and `l2` are, the relationship is that `l2` is a list of whatever `l1` is.

```
fun helper2(nil,b) = []
```

Says that `a` must be a list because `nil` has type `'a list`. Therefore, `l2` has to be a list of lists (of some type `'a`).

Question 2 and 3: I'm not quite sure how to correct the code as it is written. I'd probably write something like this:

```
fun helper2 [] accum = List.rev accum
|   helper2 ((a,b)::tl) accum =  helper2 tl (b :: a :: accum);

fun flatten2 list = helper2 list [];
```

`helper2` does all of the dirty work. If the input list is empty then we're all done and we can return the reversed *accumulator* that we've been building up. The second case is where we actually add things to the accumulator. We pattern match on the head and the tail of the list. This pattern match means that the input has type `('a * 'a) list` (a list of tuples where both elements are the same type). In the head, we have a tuple and we name the first and second element `a` and `b`, respectively. We prepend `a` then `b` onto the accumulator and recursively call `helper2` on the tail of the list. Eventually, we'll chew through all the elements in the list and then we'll be left with just the accumulator -- which, recall, has all the elements but in the reverse order. Calling `List.rev` reverses the accumulator and that's our answer.

And when I load and run it I get this:

```
- flatten2 [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)];
val it = [1,2,3,4,5,6] : int list
```